# How to calculate weight at the given saddle points

Tags: structural-engineering

Can anyone help me with the formula to calculate the weight at 'n' saddle points as done in the image[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this appears a home work problem. Also, both the question and supporting material are unclear to read.

Comment: the formula is the masses times distances must add up.  There is not enough detail here to perform the calculations.